# Name for a collection of subsets of a set $E$ such that every element of $E$ is in some member?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, definition

Let $X$ be a set.  A *partition of $X$* is a collection of subsets $\{E_\alpha\}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that the following holds.

1. For every $x\in X$, there is some $\alpha$ such that $x\in E_\alpha$.
2. For each $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$, $E_\alpha\cap E_{\alpha'}=\emptyset$.

Is there a name for a collection which is only required to satisfy the first condition?  If not, suggestions for a name I might use?  I am currently thinking "surjective collection" or "covering collection" or "semi-partition", but am not very satisfied with any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I've seen, the word **cover** is usually employed for this (no need for extra adjectives).

That is, $\{E_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}\subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a cover of $X$ precisely when $X=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha$.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, That is exactly what a cover is (after checking Wikipedia).  Sorry for the silly question.